# How do I "Open config.inc.php and fill in your MySQL database settings"?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, config

I recently purchased a php script online and need to "Open config.inc.php and fill in your MySQL database settings". I am noob at MySQL and cant find where to do it in PHPmyAdmin. Could someone tell me where to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will point you in the right direction:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: You can't do this in MySQL I recon. In your purchased script folder, there should be a file called config.inc.php. Open it, and fill in the mysql settings, which probaley means your database username,password,databasename and host (host is most likely localhost) otherwise contact your hosting provider for the details.

Comment: If you've purchased phpMyAdmin, you've paid too much — it's free software available for download at https://www.phpmyadmin.net.